# Can't upload APK to GitHub releases

Tags: github, upload

It was working five minutes ago, but now for some reason I can't seem to be able to upload an APK:

[image: APK Github]

Has it just become impossible to upload APK files to GitHub releases?
Or am I doing something the wrong way?

It happens when trying to edit a release, with an URL like https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/releases/edit/v2.3alpha22

Answer (score 1):

Does the release already have a file with the same name and filetype? If so, delete the file, save the changes, and then upload the new file. That fixed it for me.