# How to upload a JAR to GitHub releases?

Tags: github, upload

How do I use GitHub releases to upload a JAR file? Attempts to upload a JAR result in a message that ZIP files, among others are supported. JAR files *are* ZIP files, just with a different extension, of course.

I see that some people have uploaded JAR files directly into repos; is this a work-around?

For example, there is a JAR file at: https://github.com/uklance/releases/tree/master/org/lazan/tapestry-offline/0.0.1

And, yet, `GET /repos/:uklance/:releases/releases` reveals no releases.

See also [this Web Apps question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73011/).

Although GitHub **does** support upload of binaries, that answer is probably out of date.

The message is:

> Unfortunately, we don’t support that file type. Try again with a PNG, GIF, JPG, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX, TXT, PDF, or ZIP.

It seems to be same problem as here: [Can't upload APK to Github releases](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67027/cant-upload-apk-to-github-releases?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a **Release** in order to upload a JAR file, as per [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).

Or you need the [Maven-GitHub-Plugin](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: The op asked "how do I use github Releases to ...." and this answer says to create a github release?  That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag the jar into the lower part of the Release window, that says "Attach binaries by dropping them here or selecting them."

Jar **is** a supported file type for a *binary*, but it **is not** a supported file type for the release *description*.

I had the same problem, before I realized what went wrong.

Just leaving this here for future generations.

[image]